# Script for working out exponential limit within a set range

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, math, exponential

[image: Table]

In the image above column B is multiples of A1 and column C is C = C + B (working down the rows)

I worked out that in order for C for be 50 in 20 rows A1 has to be 0.2631579 but I'd like to be able to simplify that to a function that will return a list: list = exp(50, 20).

I'm not sure about the terminology of such a script so researching beforehand didn't really bring anything up sorry.

Comment: what should `list` (don't use that name) be? The lower bound of `A1`?

Comment: Yes shouldn't use that really you're right. Yes the lower bound of A1.

Comment: Furthermore `exp` is already a method of `math` and does something else.

Answer (score 1):

Well based on your problem statement, we know that:

*B<sub>n</sub>=(n-1)×a*; and *C<sub>n</sub>=(n-1)×n×a/2* (here *a* is the value for *A<sub>1</sub>*).

So we only have to solve *a* for *C<sub>20</sub>=50*. Or more genic: *C<sub>n</sub>=m*. This is simply: *a = 2×m/(n×(n-1))*.

So the function is simply:

```
def find_threshold(m,n):
    return 2.0*m/(n*(n-1))
```

For your sample input, the lower bound is:

```
>>> find_threshold(50,20)
0.2631578947368421
```

If you plug in this value in the *Excel* sheet, you will obtain 50 (although there can be small rounding errors). Given we assume calculations on the numbers are done in constant time, this script works in constant time as well (*O(1)*) so it is quite fast (even if the row number, etc. would be huge).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for your time, that would have taken me umpteen years to work out. On reflection it does look it a simple bit of mathematics so I'm going to enjoy understanding what you've done and not just copy and paste into my own code.